# How would you name this organic compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

Because there are at most seven consecutive carbon atom, and four alkyl groups attached to the chain of carbon, I would name it **2,4-tetramethyl heptane**.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's tetramethyl heptane, where are the 4 methyls? 2,4,4,6-tetramethylheptane.

Answer (score 9):

You are nearly right. You forgot to include that there is also a methyl group on carbon atom 6 and the name should also reflect that there are actually 2 methyl groups on carbon 4, so it's 2,4,4,6-tetramethylheptane.

Answer (score 0):

It is 2,4,4,6-tetramethylheptane. The parent chain is circled in red. And there are 4 methyl substituents.[image: 2,4,4,6-tetramethylheptane]